# Best way to integrate Cpp code with Python

Tags: controller, openai-gym

I'm going to make a robot simulator.
The simulator is mostly made in Python, except the controller part.
Controller is made in Cpp.
[image: Rough diagram of the simulator]

For each timestep, In simulator, robot model sends its states(motor angle, etc...) to a python method
that wraps all the codes that generates desired action according to a learned policy, that the robot has to follow. The method uses openai Gym and Machine learning codes. Then the Controller part made in Cpp gets the desired action as input and should output the specific commands that can be fed to Robot's motors.

Question is, what is the best way to use Cpp code with python. I hope that I can just send the output from Policy part to Contoller and Controller outputs the motor commands. I just want to use cpp controller part like function, like seperate black-box if possible.

Python is interpreter language, and cpp is compiler language. Google suggests some candidates like Using Cpython, Using Bootst.python or Using Pybind11. The Cpp part involves lots of `#include`s which link to controller related libraries, and will be used repeatedly during each timestep. For faster computation cpp part should be compiled just once I think.

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python (albeit that you need to scroll down to find the more modern methods as the question is from some time ago).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use pybind11 to wrap cpp.

pybind11 is pretty versatile, it supports smart pointers, and, for those who want to use eigen or vector, pybind11 converts them into numpy and list in python, respectively